# why expo publish updates app on app store?

Tags: react-native, expo

I have ejected app published in app store. I downloaded my app from app store in a device. And when I 'expo publish' ,the new update was automatically shown in my device. I am so confused. I wonder that if the local network is doing the updates or is it supposed to work like that? or how we can avoid this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply Add `enabled: false` into `app.json` solved my problem. expo version 43.0.0

```js
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0,
      "enabled": false
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

The Over-the-air updates (OTA) allows send updates easier and faster without publish a new update in the store. You can read more about OTA updates here [Over-the-air updates from Expo are now even easier to use!](https://blog.expo.dev/over-the-air-updates-from-expo-are-now-even-easier-to-use-376e2213fabf) if you want to send the update to the store, you have to upload the new version and wait until they approve the app.

> Previously, release builds of apps with expo-updates would embed the
> latest published update of your app in the binary. Now, release builds
> of both iOS and Android apps will create and embed a new update from
> the JavaScript source on disk at build-time. This new update will not
> be published automatically and will exist only in the binary with
> which it was bundled.
>
> This means you no longer need to run expo publish before creating a
> release build for the first time.
>
> This change makes the build process more flexible and similar to most
> typical React Native apps. We hope it will make getting started with
> expo-updates even easier and faster.